# Custom equation curve fitting in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use Matlab to find the values of the coeffiecients of the following equation

```
y=ax/((c+bx)*(a+cx+b))
```

I have 7 data points for y and x . How can I do this using curve fitting toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Use [least squares fitting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html):

```
 f = fittype('a*x./((c+b*x).*(a+c*x+b))');
 [fit1,gof,fitinfo] = fit(x',y',f,'StartPoint',[1 1 1]);
```

Try multiple start points to warrant a global minimum is reached.