# How to input values, plot them, and find a best fit

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, curve-fitting

I need to plot  points that have the coordinates:

```
 (0.8,825.5)
 (1.1,1096)
 (1.3,1293)
 (1.5,1404)
```

then I need to find a best-fit curve to the following equation:

```
y = x*( a1*x + a2 )*( 1 – a12*25 )
```

Where the `a1`, `a2`, and `a12` are returned.

here is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
Fzn = [0.8 1.1 1.3 1.4];
Dy = [825.5 1096 1293 1404];
x = Fzn;
y = Dy;

expr = 'x * (a1 * x + a2) * (1 - a12 * 25)';
ft = fittype(expr, 'independent', 'x', 'dependent','y');
opts = fitoptions('Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares');
opts.StartPoint = [1 1 1]; %[a1 a2 a12]
[fitresult, gof] = fit(x, y, ft, opts)

% plot
LFit = feval(fitresult, x);
figure(1);
h = plot( x,LFit,'r-', x, y,'g.');
set(h, 'LineWidth',2)
legend({'Fit Line', 'data points'}, 'Location','SouthEast')
grid on
```

I get this error:

```
Error using fit>iFit (line 127)
X must be a matrix with one or two columns.

Error in fit (line 108)
[fitobj, goodness, output, convmsg] = iFit( xdatain, ydatain,
fittypeobj, ...

Error in HatcherTireTest2 (line 113)
[fitresult, gof] = fit(x, y, ft, opts)
```

Comment: to plot multiple points use `hold on`. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667545/custom-equation-curve-fitting-in-matlab/36668335#36668335 for curve fitting

Comment: but how do i input those values/ plot them?

Comment: Do you have to this in MATLAB?
Why don't you make a simple regression using Excel?

Comment: @user2205242 This is a second order equation, a linear regression won't fit

Comment: Exactly, this is an hyperbole. What do you wanna fit in?

Comment: ive updated it with my most recent attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have one degree of freedom, so there'll be infinite solutions

```
%Put your points in a matrix
X =  [ 0.8 825.5 ; 1.1 1096 ; 1.3 1293 ; 1.5,1404 ]
plot( X(:,1) , X(:,2),'x')
hold on

%Fit the points to the equation
f = fittype('x.*( a*x + b )*( 1 – c*25 )');
[fit1,gof,fitinfo] = fit(X(:,1),X(:,2),f,'StartPoint',[1 1 1]);

%Your result is in fit1
```

Comment: i tried something like this and updated my question. but i cant get it to work

Comment: @adriaan how would you change your code based on what i just added to my question

Comment: I don't have a matlab right now, but try a, b, c instead of a1 a2 a12

Comment: i found where i had missed a * symbol and now i am getting a new less complicated error. how do i fix this?

Comment: Try traversing x and y `fit(x', y', ft, opts)`